# Execute shell in php using system

Tags: php, exec, system

I have a problem in using `system()`, `passthru()` and `exec()`, the example below will describe it better, I have a string `x` that I will use it as argument for `system()`:

```
$x = ' second_string' .$array[$i];
system("cat $x "); // not working

system("cat ".$x); // not working

system("cat { $x }"); // not working
system('cat "' . $x . '" '); // not working
system("cat second_string_xx.txt" ); //working !!
```

Comment: I guess you just missed the `.txt` suffix. Can you add the output of `var_dump($array[$i]);` ? I should also mention that you need to use `escapeshellarg()` for a safe system call

Comment: can you paste the errors if any?

Comment: maybe $x = ' second_string' .$array[$i]; have a missing trailling _, if xx is == $array[$i] content?

Comment: I should also mention that you need to use `escapeshellarg()` to quote arguments if you want to make sure that they can't contain characters which will be interpreted by the underlying shell

Comment: $array[$i] is just an array of strings(file names) it does not matter, i want to automate the execution (from system('cat some_path.txt') TO system('cat $x[i]') , i hope you understand . and about the output .. there is empty , no errors

Comment: echo $x to see what it contains.

Comment: $array=('path/file1.txt','path/file2.txt','path/file3.txt')
$x => path/file1.txt

Answer (score 0):

Your question couldn't be more vague but one of your comments suggest that you expect an error message when you feed `cat` with an invalid file. Well, that's not how `cat` actually works. As most classic Unix commands, it writes error messages into standard error (stderr) rather than standard output (stdout). You either need to use a PHP function that allows to capture stderr (such as [proc_open](http://php.net/proc_open)) or [redirect stderr to somewhere else](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) (such as stdout or a file).

Apart from that, PHP program execution functions have many optional parameters and return values and you are ignoring them all. For instance, [system()](http://php.net/system) returns the last line of the command output on success (and `FALSE` on failure) and allows to capture the return value (which will be non-zero in case of error and is the standard mechanism to detect errors).

Comment: maybe it's vague but i could not explain more ... my question simply is why it system('cat path/file.txt') works and  system ('cat '. $pathToFile) not working .

Comment: Because whatever `$pathToFile` constains, it isn't `path/file.txt`. I know you've said that "it does not matter" but it actually does.

Comment: okay , so have you any idea how to fixe it !! i am getting crazy

Comment: Define `$pathToFile` in such a way that it contains `path/file.txt`? Sorry but it's like asking why `1+2` works and `$x+$y` doesn't.

Comment: well when i print $pathToFile it works perfectly .... any way thank you for your help  :)

Comment: You'll never sort it out until you realise that computer programs only do what their code tells them to. Code does matter. Vague descriptions do not power computers.